# What is the technology stack of the StackExchange iOS app

Tags: discussion

What is the technology stack of the StackExchange iOS app, and how much does it reuse code from the website product?

Comment: Pretty much as [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225179) about Android: the apps rely on the API for most of their functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed one part of a technology stack.

Comment: The least interesting part..